# Ubuntu desktop background?

Tags: desktop-background

I run Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on both my Laptop and my Desktop.  I use the same desktop background (and same file format) on both computers.  When I power up my laptop it brings up the user login screen, and the background picture shows behind the login prompt, then my icons appear when I log in.

This doesn't happen with my Desktop however.  When I power up my desktop I get the login screen as normal, but I get the standard orange/purple background that is the default wallpaper.

How can I make the PC do the same as the laptop?

Comment: Does it fade from the orange/purple stock background to your chosen background after some time?

Comment: Do you have multiple uses on your Desktop (or did you at one point)?

Comment: Did you set both systems the same?

Comment: No, background does not fade to the new desktop from the stock background.  Did set up both systems the same way, with the same operating system, and just to make sure I even used the same format of picture file!

Comment: Don't recall ever having multiple users on my desktop - I'm the only user.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!  The issue was with the "Wallpapers" folder I created in my home folder, the permissions were not set correctly. They should have been `755`.